# Замена фигурной скобки в си

Tags: c, gcc

Недавно увидел в одном коде использование символов "<%" в качестве фигурной скобки. Сам убедился, что эти символы работают, но нигде не нашел документации на этот счет. Кто знает, это фича или баг?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Триграф_(языки_Си)

Comment: @AndrioSkur Скорее уж диграф: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%A1%D0%B8)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  да)

Comment: Термина "диграф" формально не существует. Это "альтернативные токены".

Answer (score 6):

> Кто знает, это фича или баг?

Фича. Это называется [alternative tokens](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_alternative) (или digraphs - диграфы).

Их можно использовать вместо `{ } [ ] # ##`:

```
Диграф:      <%  %>  <:  :>  %:  %:%:
Значение:    {   }   [   ]   #   ##
```

Внутри строковых и символьных литералов, а также комментариев, диграфы не обрабатываются.

В отличие от триграфов, которые обрабатываются везде:

```
Триграф:     ??<  ??>  ??(  ??)  ??=  ??/  ??'  ??!  ??-
Значение:    {    }    [    ]    #    \    ^    |    ~
```

---

Смысл всего это безобразия в том, чтобы на С можно было писать даже на экзотических кодировках, в которых недостает некоторых символов.

Не видел, чтобы это хоть где-то применялось на практике.

Comment: Еслиб в триграф воткнули запятую, было бы удобно в макросах .. :)

Answer (score 3):

Это диграф [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Диграф_(языки_Си)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%A1%D0%B8)) .
Можете также почитать про триграфы.
Я настоятельно рекомендую не использовать это